# Appium: Android Web Driver not finding Elements inside Ionic Modal

Tags: android, ionic-framework, appium

I'm trying to find elements in an Ionic Modal that appears after a click,

I'm using:

`var inputTextList = _driver.FindElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");`

It does find the items, but never find them on screen, if I want to click or send keys, it never happens,

I think that is because the driver is getting information from the page behind the modal, I realized that when I used uiautomatorviewer from android.

What's the best workaround to solve this issue?

Comment: I changed the technology, now i'm using Calabash.It is pretty much easyer to have access to web driver and even crosswalk for hybrid applications made with Ionic or Cordova